# Django post request data

Tags: python, django, python-requests

Im trying to post data to my Django server but when I check the server the Querydict is empty. When I call from the browser it does look good.

```
import requests
import json
headers =  {
       "AUTHORIZATION": "1234",
       "Content-type": "application/json",
       "Accept": "text/plain"
    }
print headers    

payload = {
    "start_date_s":"04/01/2016",
    "start_date_e":"04/15/2016"
}


r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/get-ticket-data',headers=headers, json = json.dumps(payload))
print r.content
print r.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `json` argument, you should pass your dict as is, don't dump it ([docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)):

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/get-ticket-data',headers=headers, json=payload)
```

Comment: data=json.dumps(payload) or data=payload, in both cases the data is sent in request.body

Comment: my bad..the problem was the content-type in the header..I have to remove it  as its JSON or change it to multiform-data

Answer (score 0):

if you send json request, you need to use `request.body` in django view to get the that, not `request.POST`